# Referenced figures showing Fig ?? instead of Figure number

Tags: graphics, floats, cross-referencing

I have figure in my Thesis, which I produced as follows

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{line11}
    \caption{The path}
 \label{fig:f1}   
\end{figure}
```

I referenced it using `Fig. \ref{f1}`.

It appeared in the list of figures but wherever I referenced it I have a Fig ??

Comment: You need to use the full label `\ref{fig:f1} `

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the O.P. did not specify the correct label name